# js клик при обновлении части страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Добрый день!

Я столкнулся с трудностью при получении события click после обновления части страницы через $.post.

click не ловит элементы которые были обновлены, хотя они удовлетворяют его требования.

Подскажите, как выйти из ситуации. Нужен метод который сможет ловить click даже после перезагрузки части страницы.

Comment: ну если jquery то jQuery(document).on('click','селектор'.function(e){});

т.е. не вешатся прям на сами объекты а на document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться делегированием событий. Суть способа в том, что события не привязываются к конкретным элементам, а навешиваются на документ или какой-то общий корневой элемент. Далее, благодаря всплытию событий, мы можем получить нужный нам клик на корневом элементе, через объект события получить его источник, сравнить с нужным нам и выполнить действие.

Хорошее описание методики: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

На jQuery это делается очень просто:

```
$(document).on('click', '.any_element', function () {
    // выполняем действие
});
```